# Mail for Mac will not accept my password

Tags: mail.app, email

I have an imac running OSX 10.6.8 on which Mail for Mac 4.6 is installed. I use this app to access my .mac account - this being a MobileMe IMAP account. Since midday today I have been unable to access my inbox or send mail - I am repeatedly told my password is wrong. I have repeatedly reentered my password to no avail. I am able to access my account through iCloud (web based) using my usual password, so clearly I know the password and am not entering it wrongly in Mail. I have checked all the other IMAP and STMP settings - they are correct.
I am also able to access the account through my father's iPad - but have had to set up 2 factor authentication for this to happen. I am wondering if I need 2 factor to access from Mail - but cannot find any way of generating or entering such a password. Help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up an app-specific password, which is now mandatory on anything connecting to iCloud that doesn't support 2FA. See Apple's current instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397), but they may change over time and so shouldn't be included in an answer.
If the link no longer works, search for "icloud app-specific password".

You will need to set up two-step (not two-factor, which your iMac doesn't support) authentication on your iCloud account.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I had come to suspect. I was advised by Apple that this may be the case, that an app specific password may be required,  but got the impression that it only applied to 3rd party apps - i.e. apps not provided by Apple with the computer. I have now set up the necessary password and all is back to normal.

Comment: @jeremy Mail on a macOS version as old as 10.6.8 counts as a third-party app for these purposes -- it's not had the benefit of the last five years of Apple's security changes.